# message : "invalid version specified"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

For some reason the Facebook login SDK is giving this error: message
:"invalid version specified".

I've simply copied the code from their site:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '{my app id is here}',
  cookie     : true,
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : '{v3.0}'
});

FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   

};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "this error"? Is it possible that the version should not be given in brackets?

Comment: The curly braces are only used in the documentation to signal “this is a placeholder you need to replace” - they are not part of the actual value you need to supply. `'{v3.0}'` needs to be `'v3.0'`

Comment: Just pointing that for those, as me, will load the script dynamically, make sure the "v" is before the number or it won't work (since the type is Object:FacebookSDKVersionNumber)